# How to return first value meeting condition and stop (sub-)query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to find a translation for a word, using a subquery for another table, joining by the word that needs to be translated. It works, but it makes the query very slow, because the table containing the translation is quite huge.

```
select name, 
       (select name_en 
        from translations 
        where name = a.name 
          and name is not null 
          and name != '' 
        order by name_en desc 
        limit 1) as name_en 
from original_table as a;
```

In my case it would be sufficient to just return the first value that meets the where clause of the subquery and then return it (without the ordering or `limit 1`). Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want *any* of the translations, do away with the `ORDER BY` clause and

```
CREATE INDEX ON translations (name);
```

Make sure that you put constraints on the translation table to improve performance and data quality:

- define all columns `NOT NULL`: it is pointless to have NULL values there.
- add a check constraint that forbids empty strings
- make sure to have a unique constraint on `name` (it could be the primary key)

Then you can omit those extra checks, you don't nee the `LIMIT`, and you can convert the subquery to an outer join, which may boost performance for larger queries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The table is not actually a translation table, I just named it that way. In fact it holds similar objects like the outer table, but they can only be joined by the name field. For the table itself it is perfectly legal to have empty strings for translation columns, so both empty-string-constraint and unique constraint on the name column won't work in my case

Comment: Then you can only create the index and have to live with NULL values and `LIMIT 1`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a slightly different index.  First, I strongly encourage you to write the query *qualifying all column names*:

```
select ot.name, 
       (select t.name_en 
        from translations t
        where t.name = ot.name 
              t.name <> '' 
        limit 1
       ) as name_en 
from original_table ot;
```

From your description, no `order by` is needed.  The `NULL` comparison is redundant, so you can just remove it.  I'm also not sure if `t.name <> ''` is needed.  There are probably no matches on empty strings anyway.

The index is `translates(name, name_en)`.  Postgres now supports index-only scans (under some circumstances).  If all the rows are "visible", then this can be resolved only using the index.